# how can i retrive jpa-repository instance from class in spring 2.2.4.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

i need to retrieve specific instance of jpa-repository from an entity class to call findAll, findOne ecc...

```
Entity entity = getRepository(EntityClass).findOne(uriParamValue);
```

In the previous spring version (1.5.X) i was doing it this way:

```
public JpaRepository<Entity, Serializable> getRepository(Class<?> javaClass) {
    return (JpaRepository<Entity, Serializable>) repositories.getRepositoryFor(javaClass);
}
```

but in spring 2.2.X the Repository class interfaces has been changed from:

```
public Object getRepositoryFor(Class<?> domainClass) {
```

to:

```
public Optional<Object> getRepositoryFor(Class<?> domainClass) {
```

and i can't cast "Optional getRepositoryFor(X)" to JpaRepository instance to able to call JpaRepository methods.

Where am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `getRepositoryFor` method, but [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) is a standard Java class intruduced in Java SE 8.
You can check if the value is present and get the actual value from the Optional if it is present. Here is a sample using [orElseThrow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)), but there are also other variants. Checkout the Javadoc.

```
public JpaRepository<Entity, Serializable> getRepository(Class<?> javaClass) {
    return (JpaRepository<Entity, Serializable>) repositories.getRepositoryFor(javaClass)
           .orElseThrow(() -> new MyException());
}
```